# How do I set MATE 1.6 to use Compiz?

Tags: compiz, mate

MATE desktop has recently migrated, as of version 1.6, from using `mateconf-editor` to `gsettings`. This breaks traditional solutions for changing MATE's window manager to Compiz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have already installed Compiz. If not:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz
```

`gsettings` has an equivalent operation to the `mateconf-editor` key-change operation you had to do to set the window manager to Compiz. Now, to activate Compiz, simply run the following terminal command:

```
sudo gsettings set org.mate.session.required-components windowmanager compiz
```

This will change the `windowmanager` key to `compiz` in the `org.mate.session.required-components` schema. Next, I highly recommend installing CompizConfig Settings Manager:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

With this, you are done. You may either run `compiz --replace` in the Terminal to start Compiz, or simply reboot your machine. I recommend the latter, as the former may have problems.

Comment: no joy. I'm using `ubuntu 14.10 mate` and when I've restarted the top bar of all windows is missing

Comment: Hmm. I don't use Ubuntu anymore, but try running `gtk-window-decorator --replace` after the system boots up?