# no graphic card performance on Mate desktop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, compiz, ccsm, mate

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 and installed my Nvidia graphic card proprietary drivers 
! and that worked fine with the compiz effects ! then i installed Mate desktop but there those effects disappeared seems like the graphic card driver doesn't do job anymore on Mate !

Comment: Maybe you just need to enable compiz on Mate... see if this helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/297006/how-do-i-set-mate-1-6-to-use-compiz

Comment: you saved my day !